# Getting attributes to bleed through to children

Tags: css, css-float

I want to simulate tabs such that the first word in a list entry always gets a fixed width.  I do it like this:

```
<style>
.tabbed { float: left; width: 5em; }
</style>

<ul>
<li><span class='tabbed'>first</span> entry in my list</li>
<li><span class='tabbed'>second</span> list entry</li>
</ul>
```

the approach works relatively well except that if I want to do:

```
li { color: blue }
```

it applies the color (not surprisingly) to the `<li>` but not to the `<span>`.  this means that I would have to:

```
.tabbed { color: blue }
```

which is not very DRY.  In my case I've got a whole bunch of declarations for different classes of the list items so it's cumbersome and ugly.

how does one deal with this?

Comment: I don't see a problem with this.  Can you show more of your styles?

Comment: Unless the `.tabbed` has a color applied to it previously, it should also be colored blue by doing the li { color: blue; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the the `span` should be colored blue if the `li` is colored blue.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Q2UGE/ for an example

I think you must have some other CSS overriding it

In case you do have something else overriding it that you cant change, you can also enforce `li .tabbed` to inherit from it parent

```
li .tabbed { color: inherit }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Q2UGE/1/ for an example of that

Comment: I can see you're quite correct.  I need to go figure out what else may be going on with my code now.  thanks for taking the time to prove the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really. Best you could do is...

```
li,
.tabbed { 
    color: blue 
}
```

Comment: Would `li .tabbed { color: inherit }` not be better?

Comment: @Petah It would so the same thing, I'm not sure if it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
li, .tabbed { color: blue }
```

thats a little more dry.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
li, .tabber { color: blue }
```